# Using gradle typed tasks how can we exclude different types of files?

Tags: gradle

Using Gradle typed task how can we exclude file copy for file names starting with as well as ending with some strings?

```
def contentSpec = copySpec {
  exclude {
    it.file.name.startsWith('img')
    it.file.name.endsWith('gif')
  }
  from 'src'
}

task copyImages (type: Copy) {
  with contentSpec
  into 'Dest'
}
```

On running `gradle copyImages`, it excludes files ending with gif, but does not exclude files starting with img.

Is there a way to achieve both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot an or (`||`) between your two conditions:

```
exclude { it.file.name.startsWith('img') || it.file.name.endsWith('gif') }
```

The value of a closure is the value of its last expression. Since the last expression, in your code, is `it.file.name.endsWith('gif')`, that's the value of the closure, and the file is thus excluded when `it.file.name.endsWith('gif')` is true.

Of course, you could also use two exclusions:

```
exclude {
  it.file.name.startsWith('img')
}
exclude {
  it.file.name.endsWith('gif')
}
```